# Nestjs using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, nestjs

> This simple demo has an error
>    *https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module*

```
import { Get, Controller, HttpService } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly http: HttpService) {}
  @Get()
  root(): Observable<AxiosResponse<any>>  {
    return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/januwA');
  }
}
```

What should I do?

```
[Nest] 7356   - 2018-10-18 00:08:59   [ExceptionsHandler] Converting circular structure to JSON +9852ms
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

---

```
nest i
common version : 5.1.0
core version   : 5.1.0
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You cannot just return the whole `AxiosResponse` object because it cannot be serialized to JSON. You most likely want to get the response `data` like this:

```
@Get()
root() {
  return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/januwA').pipe(
    map(response => response.data)
  );
}
```

---

or alternatively using `Promises`:

```
@Get()
async root() {
  const response = await this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/januwA').toPromise();
  return response.data;
}
```

Comment: toPromise is going to be deprecated, refer to documentation https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise

Comment: to handle errors from the http services use `catchError` function after the map.

Answer (score 4):

You have to make sure to handle your responses as a JSON you can return it as a promise and get the data, use one of both or HttpService or axios

```
import { Get, Controller, HttpService } from '@nestjs/common';
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly http: HttpService) {}
  @Get()
      root(): {
        return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/quen2404')
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res.data)
        .catch(err => /*handle error*/)
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`toPromise()` is deprecated so this is the updated answer:

```js
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
...
const response = await firstValueFrom(this.httpService.get('/api'));
return response.data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

as you write in your example, `get` method return `AxiosResponse<>` and contains circular reference. 
So if you want to proxify webservice `https://api.github.com/users/januwA`, you should return [`AxiosResponse.data`](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) :

```
import { Get, Controller, HttpService } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly http: HttpService) {}
  @Get()
  root(): Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.get('https://api.github.com/users/quen2404')
      .pipe(map(response => response.data));
  }
}
```