# How to fix AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN at index [0] is available in the Module context

Tags: node.js, axios, httprequest, nestjs, httpservice

I am using  Axios in my project to call some third-party endpoints.  I don't seem to understand the
error

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the HttpService (?). Please make sure that the argument 
AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN at index [0] is available in the TimeModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN is a provider, is it part of the current TimeModule?
- If AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TimeModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN */ ]
  })
```

This is the module

```
@Module({
  imports: [TerminalModule,],
  providers: [TimeService, HttpService],
  controllers: [TimeController]
})
export class TimeModule { }
```

This is the service

```
@Injectable()
export class TimeService {
    constructor(private httpService: HttpService,
        @InjectModel('PayMobileAirtime') private time: Model<Time>,       
        @Inject(REQUEST) private request: any,

    ) { }
```

This is an example of one of my **get** and **post** methods

```
 async PrimeAirtimeProductList(telcotime: string) {
        let auth = await this.TimeAuth()
        const productList = await this.httpService.get(`https://clients.time.com/api/top/info/${telcotime}`,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth.token}`
                }
            }
        ).toPromise();

        return productList.data
    }
```

Post

```
const dataToken = await this.manageTimeAuth()
        const url = `https://clients.time.com/api/dataup/exec/${number}`

        const BuyTelcoData = await this.httpService.post(url, {
            "product_id": product_id,
            "denomination": amount,
            "customer_reference": reference_id
        }, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${dataToken.token}`
            }
        }).toPromise();

        const data = BuyTelcoData.data;
```

Comment: Please provide code for HttpService as well. Also, what exactly AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN 
 is and where is it defined?

Comment: My code has been updated

Comment: Try adding "HttpModule" in the "imports" arrary in "TimeModule" module. Make sure to import it first in the module.

Comment: See this https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Import `HttpModule` from `@nestjs/common` in `TimeModule` and add it to the `imports` array.

Remove `HttpService` from the `providers` array in `TimeModule`. You can directly import it in the `TimeService`.

```
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/common';
...

@Module({
    imports: [TerminalModule, HttpModule],
    providers: [TimeService],
    ...
})
```

TimeService:

```
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/common';
```

If your response type is an `Observable` of type `AxiosResponse`, then import these two as well in the service file `TimeService`.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
```

For reference, check out [http-module](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859515/nestjs-using-axios).

Comment: FYI: This solution also works for the new `import { HttpModule} from '@nestjs/axios';`

Answer (score 20):

Don't pass HttpService in the providers. Import only HttpModule.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But can you explain why it worked ?

Comment: Because `imports` takes the list of modules that export the providers. By default the providers are encapsulated. Providers can be directly used in the services. Meaning HttpService can be directly used in the TimeService.

Have a look at the documentation here [Nest Modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules) _This means that it's impossible to inject providers that are neither directly part of the current module nor exported from the imported modules. Thus, you may consider the exported providers from a module as the module's public interface, or API._

Answer (score 0):

This works!

Just import this

```
import { HttpModule} from '@nestjs/axios';
```

and then add it to @Module's import, do not add HttpService in the providers.