# Nest.js RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: typescript, axios, nestjs

I want to make a request to to an external api using axios and nestjs.

I took this answer [Nestjs using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52864503/12753324) and instead of execute the request in the controller I created a service

```
// controller
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CollectService } from './collect.service';


@Controller('collect')
export class CollectController {
    constructor(private collectService: CollectService) {}


    @Get()
    getResponse(){
         this.getResponse();

    }
   

}

// ----------service ------------------------

import { Injectable, HttpService } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class CollectService {

    constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}


    async getResponse() {
       
        const response = await this.httpService.get('https://reqres.in/api/users/2').toPromise();
        return response.data;

    
     
        }
      
}
```

which gave me a stackoverflow

```
[Nest] 23928   - 02/28/2021, 12:16:18 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] Maximum call stack size exceeded +74479ms
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

what caused this behavior ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You call controller's `getResponse()` infinity, then it throws `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

I think you want to call the service's function instead:

```
    @Get()
    getResponse(){
         this.collectService.getResponse();

    }
```

Comment: This morning was though, I faced the same problem.

Comment: This not correct.